# How to save a form by pjax and non-pjax in yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii2, render, pjax

I have a form as follow:

```
<?php widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'conference', 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(), enableAjaxValidation' => true, 'validationUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['validation'])]); ?> 
           <?php echo $form->field($model, 'eTitle')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>  
           <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-grid']) ?>   
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php widgets\Pjax::end();?>
```

and I've written follow Jquery for ajax:

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

    $('.conference').on('beforeSubmit', 'form#{$model->formName()}', function(e) {
        var \$form = $(this);
        $.post(
            \$form.attr("action"),
            \$form.serialize()
        )
        .done(function(result) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(result);
            var responseStatus = result['status'];
            switch (responseStatus) {
                case 'success':              
                   alert(result['message']);
                    var url = 'index.php?r=paper-conference/create';
                    $.pjax.reload({container:'#conferences', url:url, timeout: false , push: false, replace: false});
                    $('#modal').modal('hide');
                    break;
                case 'fail':
                    //T0 D0: Change to Message Box 
                    alert(result['message']);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            //T0 D0: do error log
            alert('server error');
        });
        return false;
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

this form renders in two way, as a modal and sometimes as a normal form. when it is renderd as a modal, I want to save form and show an `alert('successfull')` and then close modal.

if it is rendered as a normal form(not modal), I want to save by postback and not use pjax.

at the moment, it works well when it is rendered as a modal, saved and then modal is closed. but I don't know How to render as a normal form and disable pjax. I have tried by

```
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-grid', 'data-pjax' => 0]) ?>
```

but it doesn't work and is saved by ajax.

here is my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model = new Conference();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($model->save()) {
               echo 'successfull';

            }
        } else {
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
                return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
                    'model' => $model,

                ]);
            return $this->render('_form', [
                'model' => $model,

            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution : Also Check `Yii::$app->request->isAjax` in view if not ajax request then do not register js.

Comment: @InsaneSkull thank u. it was simple but very usefull.